# Redirect .com to .org in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have domain.com and domain.org as aliases pointing to the same vhost. How can I use .htaccess to redirect all domain.com requests to domain.org?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to do this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.org$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.org%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This rule redirects every request that’s not addressed to `example.org` to the very same.

Comment: What if the server was a virtual server with other hosts. What might the mod_rewrite rule(s) look like to only redirect widget.com to widget.org? Would it be RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^widget\.com$ Thanks

Comment: Try this: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.(example\.com|example\.org)$|^example\.com$`

Comment: Odd question: do you personally require attribution for us to use this code snippet? Or can I bypass that? I don't truly even know how to properly give attribution based on CC 3.0

Comment: @D.Tate From the page’s footer: “user contributions licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)”

Comment: @Gumbo Thanks, yeah I know about that but didn't know if you care about that personally..? Like, since you wrote it, I think you can personally say that you will allow others to use it without attribution. I know you have a high score so you probably have posted lots of snippets and stuff on this site. I've never even read the full CC 3.0 legal document. But if you want attribution, do you have an example of how to do that? (sorry for clogging up this comment area)

Comment: @D.Tate I would be glad to get proper attribution. But I’m neither sure about the licensing nor how the proper attribution would look like for a code snippet.

Comment: @Gumbo Hey sorry, I hate being a pest about this stuff. But i think you can just tell me "include my alias, Gumbo, and a link to my profile" or something like that, and I will just do that. Or maybe I won't lol . This might be a fair use situation anyway. Either way, thanks for the chat, we can be done now. you can delete all these if you want

Comment: @D.Tate At least include the URL to this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Redirects all www/non-www of `domain.com` to `domain.org`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```