# Is there a way to create a redirection with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, alias

I have a domain name and an alias which look like this :
      mydomain.com
      mydomain.ca

I want to create a redirection. When a user write mydomain.com, I would like to be redirect on mydomain.ca.

I tried this code but it don't seem to work with what I want to do : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803432/redirect-com-to-org-in-htaccess)

Comment: Can you include the htaccess code you have tried?

Comment: That solution looks like it's *exactly* what you want to do, what is it doing or not doing?

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^boutiquegriffon\.ca$
RewriteRule ^ http://boutiquegriffon.ca%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Comment: @Jewb: No need for the `RewriteEngine` when there is a built in redirect rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very simple - use the [`Redirect` directive.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#Redirect)

Example:

```
Redirect permanent / http://mydomain.ca
```

This code should go in your .htaccess file and be uploaded to the root of mydomain.com.

Alternatively, if they're on the same virtual host, you can use`mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://mydomain.ca%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The `R` flag also indicates the HTTP status code (301 - Moved Permanently).

Comment: I got this message : This webpage has a redirect loop.

Comment: Are they both on the same virtual host?